# How to spawn enemies in a mixed pattern based off ratios

Tags: javascript, algorithm, unityscript

Let's say you have four enemy types: **Basic, Strong, Poison, and Flying**. For each level in the game, they each have their own spawning frequencies, which results in ratios of: **0.4, 0.3, 0.2, and 0.1** respectively.

Is there a way to infinitely spawn these different enemy types in a way that they appear in a perfect pattern where the different types of enemy appear in an order as evenly mixed as possible? (Like skittles.)

Example ratios of the above enemy types would be: **BBBB, SSS, PP, F**. So turned into a pattern could maybe look like: **BSBPSFBSPB** (Although I'm not even sure how I came to that result, it's mostly by guesstimation of how it may look.)

I could manually code the spawning pattern for each level in the game, but there will be hundreds of levels. Setting their appearance frequency is easier but I don't know how to code that into a mixed pattern.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you show an example of a pattern?

Comment: Why not just make it random?

Comment: @Bergi random wouldn't make it linear.

Comment: Example ratios of the above enemy types would be: BBBB, SSS, PP, F. So turned into a pattern could maybe look like: BSBPSFBSPB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
function generatePattern(ratios, length) {
    var pattern = new Array(length);
    for (var i=0; i<ratios.length; i++) {
        var ratio = ratios[i];
        var step = 1 / ratio;
        for (j=0; j<length; j+=step) {
            var ind = Math.floor(j);
            while (ind in pattern)
                ind++;
            pattern[ind] = i; // element for which the ratio stands
        }
    }
   pattern.length = length; // chop off overflow
    return pattern;
}
```

Example:

```
> generatePattern([.4,.3,.2,.1], 10)
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3] // and then repeat that forever
```

Yet you will need to choose the length "correctly" so that the ratios are possible - if not, the smaller ones will get suppressed. Also, because of the floating point maths it may come to incorrect results.

Comment: This is a great idea — I was thinking along the lines of somehow generating a pattern but you actually have a mind able to figure it out :)

Comment: Did you test the code? It's very close to working but not quite correct results. The example is coming up with the result: **3001021001**. The `while (ind in pattern)` portion doesn't seem to be executing anything.

Comment: Yes, I tested it for some inputs and got the result which I posted above… (copied from console). The `while` loop is supposed to prevent overlapping, it advances `ind` as long as it is already claimed. Maybe this part does not work correct for all combinations of ratios, the actual idea was a more functional one: Merging (infinite) streams of object/no-object values to one output, with one stream for each ratio.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with while in. It doesn't appear to be working in Unity. Is there an alternative way you'd write that segment?

Comment: Nah, that's not a special loop syntax. It's just a normal `while` statement combined with the `in` operator - if you think that is what is not working you could try `while (typeof pattern[ind] == "number") ind++;`

Comment: Still couldn't get that to work for some reason but decided to initialize the array to -1 and then say `while (pattern[ind] > -1) ind++;` It's working perfectly now, thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using timers for your spawn routines, what you could do is use the lowest frequency, 0.1, as the base ratio. Say for a level 0.1 is every 4 seconds. You set the timer for this spawn to 4s, then the timer for spawn 0.2 at 2 seconds (4s/2), the timer for spawn 0.3 at 1.3333 seconds (4s/3) and the basic spawn 0.4 at 1s (4s/4).

If you don't want the spawns to overlap, you have to figure out a time delay between spawns so that no two spawns will happen at the same time.

Comment: But then at some ticks 4 enemies would spawn at once?

Comment: True. Unless you introduce a delay for the 4 timers.

Comment: Yes. But I think the OP wants to know how to choose that delay…